# Expand Environment Variables in string and store the result in another variable

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, batch, environment-variables

This may sound a bit silly, as I am not a regular Batch script programmer.

How do I expand any Environment Variable inside a string and store the final expanded output into another variable, means like below:

```
@echo off
set P1="%SYSTEMROOT%\Temp"
echo %%P1%%
```

This should print "C:\Windows\Temp" before exiting. And this should also work if I first elevate the script to admin then run the same code like below:

```
@echo off
net file 1>nul 2>nul && goto :RunAsAdmin^
 || powershell -ex unrestricted -Command "Start-Process -Verb RunAs -FilePath '%comspec%' -ArgumentList '/c %~fnx0 %*'"
goto :eof
:RunAsAdmin
set P1="%systemroot%\Temp"
echo %%P1%%
```

Should print the same output as given above. Can anyone help figuring what I am doing wrong here?

P.S. I asked this, as I wanna be able to smartly clear the System Temp directory by declaring the path in a variable and reusing the variable in the next commands like below:

```
set P1="%systemroot%\Temp" && del /f /s /q %%P1%%\*.* && rd /s /q %%P1%%\*
```

Comment: Why are you using `%%`? Replace them with `%`.

Comment: Still after doing that, it doesn't work....

Comment: Put a `pause` on the last line and try `echo %P1%` - in both scripts (elevated and not) it prints `"C:\WINDOWS\Temp"`  while  `echo %%P1%%` in both cases prints `%P1%` .  See [How-to: Double %% symbols, why are they needed in a batch file?](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-percent.html)

Comment: Alright, then it should print the same output when I use like this `@echo off
set P1="%SYSTEMROOT%\Temp\*" && echo %P1%
pause
` but in this case it just prints `echo is off`, weird and unwanted behaviour....

Comment: You can't do `@echo off set P1="%SYSTEMROOT%\Temp\*" && echo %P1%` all in one line. Split it over 2 lines and it will work.

Comment: No, `@echo off` and `set P1=%SYSTEMROOT%\Temp\* && echo %P1%` are on different lines already. It's just that, when I pasted the code in comment here, it was displayed like so...And that too didn't work as expected...

Comment: It prints `ECHO is off` because P1 is not set - see [Why this code says echo is off?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14335100/2953889).  Put  `set P1="%systemroot%\Temp"` and `echo %P1%` (and `pause`) on separate lines like you have in your question.

Comment: If you're on Windows 10, and "not a Batch programmer", why are you working in Batch and not **PowerShell**? It is the default console & scripting language for Windows. Batch & cmd will disappear at some point.

Answer (score 1):

- Just replace....

  ---

1) **`%comspec%`** + **`-ArgumentList '/c`** + **`%~fnx0 %`** to:

```bat
Start-Process $env:windir\system32\cmd.exe -Verb RunAs -Argument $env:cmd_arg
```

---

2) Your **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)** command does not require quotes, remove them

```bat
%__APPDIR__%\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ex unrestricted -Command Start-Process $env:windir\system32\cmd.exe -Verb RunAs -Argument $env:cmd_arg
```

---

3) Remove quotes/semi-quotes from **`'/c %~fnx0 %*'`** and replace to **`$env:cmd_arg`**

---

4) For **`%%P1%%`**, try using:

---

```bat
cmd /v /c "echo !P1!"
call echo/ %P1%
echo/ %P1%
echo= %P1%
echo[ %P1%
echo( %P1%
echo. %P1%
```

---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion


title <nul && Title ...\%~nx0
%__APPDIR__%mode.com con: cols=99 lines=3
for %%i in (%*)do set "_arg=!_arg! "%%~i" "

set "cmd_arg= /v /c "%~fnx0" !_arg!" && %__APPDIR__%Net.exe file 2>nul >nul && (
      goto :RunAsAdmin 
      ) || (
      color 9f & echo/ Running your PowerShel cmdlets...
      set "_ps1=%__APPDIR__%\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
      !_ps1! -ex unrestricted -Command Start-Process $env:windir\system32\cmd.exe -Verb RunAs -Argument $env:cmd_arg
      echo/ Press any key to exit... && %__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1 >nul & endlocal && goto :EOF
      )

echo/ If you see this, sorry it doesn't work... && goto :EOF

:RunAsAdmin
%__APPDIR__%mode.com 99,25 && color 0A

echo/If you see this one, it works sr. Admin^!!... 
title <nul && Title ...\%~nx0 

rem ::  do your admin tasks here....
echo/ Press any key to exit... && %__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1 >nul
endlocal && goto :EOF
```

Comment: When I run the full code after replacing `rem./ goto :eof or... && goto :Next` with `pause>nul` it gives error: `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe "C:\LocalWebServer\Nginx1161\html\DiskCleanerTest2.bat"
Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
'"C:\LocalWebServer\Nginx1161\html\DiskCleanerTest2.bat" '.
At line:1 char:1 ....`

Comment: Now it gives different error, when I repeat the same steps as mentioned in above comment. Error: `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "C:\LocalWebServer\Nginx1161\html\DiskCleanerTest.cmd"
Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Process -Verb RunAs -FilePath $env:cmd_arg`

Comment: That's the file, whose code I have put in Question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104537/discussion-between-vicky-dev-and-it-wasnt-me).

Comment: Why is there any powershell-reference in the answer? Is a batch-question.

Comment: @Carsten Hi there! Why didn't you ask too: *Why is there any cmd-reference in the answer?*

Comment: @Carsten There is no obligation to put any reference, but they help a lot, the fact that they don't have any, several other answers of mine have. I'll edit and post references to cmd and ps1 as soon as I have time..